# SQL Need help in a stored procedure for assigning values to parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

example, There is a result column in the table, if 10 students are present in the table and all of them have a value "PASS" then we should assign to a parameter @TotalResult as "Pass",. if any one of the student " Fails" in 10 students the parameter should assign the value to "Fail"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXIsTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable Where result = 'Fail') 
 BEGIN
    SET @TotalResult = 'Fail'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET @TotalResult = 'Pass'
 END
```

**UPDATE**
As specified in comments change the condition to

```
 IF EXIsTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable Where result <> 'Pass' AND  result <> 'absent')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd like to give another +1 for doing "Select 1" instead of "Select *"

Comment: actually "pass" and "absent" or two good cases and these are constant values and when these two values are present we should assign the parameter as "Pass"

Comment: but "Fail" value is not constant it can contain any value "Fail" or any subject name in the result. so we should only see if its (Pass\Absent) assign "Pass" else "Fail"

Comment: @user3494425 you should have included that in your question!

Comment: @RajeshDhiman This was my first time posting a question, little confused, sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Stage_EmployeeISIRegister Where result <> 'S' OR  result <> 'Updated' and [ISIFileImportID]=169)
BEGIN
    SET TotalResult = 'Pass'
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET TotalResult = 'Fail'
 END
 
Even if total result are "S" even then it printing TotalResult as Fail
not working as expected

Comment: Don't forget the correct use of brackets `Where (result <> 'S' OR result <> 'Updated') AND ([ISIFileImportID]=169))`  and it should be `@TotalResult` not `TotalResult`.

Comment: I was not able to give more then one @ symbol in Comment box so i took them out, i replaced or with "AND" its working correctly.. Thanks :)